# Add columns based on indexing in rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
df =
     Group    lst                    
0      A      [0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
1      B      [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
2      C      [0,0,1,0]
3      D      [0,1,0,1,0]
```

I want to add a column with a list containing the indices of all 1 items in that row and another column with the length of the list. So the desired output is

```
df_output =
     Group    lst                    one_inds    lst_count
0      A      [0,0,1,0,1,0,0]        [2,4]       7
1      B      [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]    [0,1,7]     9
2      C      [0,0,1,0]              [2]         4
3      D      [0,1,0,1,0]            [1,3]       5
```

For a given list `lst` I can do

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 1]
```

As well as `len(lst)` for counting. But not sure how to do it row-wise or add the results as columns.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You get the length of lists in a column with `pd.Series.str.len`. We can use `np.where` to get the indices, assuming 1 and 0 are the only possible values (Though it's a slow apply over the rows).

```
import numpy as np

df['one_inds'] = df['lst'].apply(lambda x: np.where(x)[0].tolist())
df['lst_count'] = df['lst'].str.len()

  Group                          lst   one_inds  lst_count
0     A        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]     [2, 4]          7
1     B  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  [0, 1, 7]          9
2     C                 [0, 0, 1, 0]        [2]          4
3     D              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]     [1, 3]          5
```

---

Other ways to get the `'ones_ind'` column.

```
#If lists can have other values, use an array
df['ones_ind'] = df['lst'].apply(lambda x: np.where(np.array(x) == 1)[0].tolist())

# List comprehensions can be faster than `apply`
df['ones_ind'] = [[i for i,val in enumerate(x) if val == 1] for x in df['lst']]
```